# This add new member code worked fine until I switched webhosts for my site now it does not and I have no idea why

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am having an issue with my adding a new member page,, also having an issue with my login  page which is similar in code. Both worked fine, tested multiple times and ways and then I switched hosting companies. The rest of the database driven site works fine still except this part. Have no idea why and possibly just need fresh eyes on it. I am fairly new to php and mysql to begin with,,, then attempting to learn the newer versions to keep my code upgraded has me at this point unable to figure out why the code is no longer working. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

The page will run up to this point,, I have confirmed that using echo, then it fails. The page itself, does not load, justs stays completely blank and the little loading wheel in the tab corner just spins and spins.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE field LIKE'$username'";
$rs=$db->query($sql);
$arr = $rs->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
// test to make sure there was not an issue loading the db
if($rs != true) {  // start second if in nested section
    // if any errors in reading the db redirect to a general db is down error page
    //close db connection
    mysqli_close($db);
    // redirect header goes here, removed for this post
} else { // else to go with second if
    // get number of rows returned in this case should be 0 or 1
    $rows_returned = $rs->num_rows;
    echo "num of rows are $rows_returned";
} // end second if
```

Comment: at exactly WHICH line does this fail? As written, there's nothing wrong with this code. It could use some major improvements, but it's not "wrong".

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: A good place to start will be getting phpinfo() output for both new and old hosts and compare them.

Comment: As you switched webhosts, have you verified database credential(s) and configuration(s)? Does this script use the same configuration/database-interaction as the rest of the "database driven site"? It might be using a different library with a different configuration file, for example

Comment: The line of code that is directly before where I posted from is this if ($pos != "" && $pos2 != "") {  // start first if in nested section, I used echo to see if it entered the if and found a position for both those variables and it echo'd back the right values, then once I moved the echo down a bit to test this next section it stopped working.

Comment: Try throwing in the good old: `ini_set("display_errors","On"); error_reporting(-1);` -- see if you get anything useful from that.

Comment: I believe that the configurations are the same, I will double check right now,,, cannot do a php_info for old host as account has been cancelled as of last week.

Comment: mysqli is probably disabled in your php.ini

Comment: I have checked the configurations and they are fine

Comment: mysqli is not disabled as the rest of the site is using it as well and runs fine

Comment: I am thinking that somewhere within the query itself it fails because it does not seem to enter the if statement below the query.  The ini_set does not do anything either,, just get that spinning wheel and totally blank page

Comment: $sql="SELECT * FROM registeredMembers WHERE userName LIKE '$username'";
 $rs=mysqli_query($db, $sql);
 $arr = $rs->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
   echo "test";
                 echo $rs;

Comment: I have tried changing the recordset code to the type I used for the rest of the site,, still no luck,, also added 2 testing echos right after the query and nothing shows on the page, I am thinking for sure the db is not being read but not sure how I can tell or what is exactly wrong. I have double checked to make sure that the right user, pass are being used, and it is configured correctly, the site is configured for php5.5 and mysqli ... that is about all I have come up with.

Comment: Also I echo'd the variable that holds the userid from the form post method and it echos fine on the screen before the query but does not echo after the query.

Comment: Getting back to this finally,, just in case anyone reads this later... it was the Fetch_All that it did not like. once I changed the coding of that so I was not using Fetch_All anymore it works fine... later I did read an notice that in order to use Fetch_All you must have mysql native driver... so I am assuming that this new hosting company does not.  Thanks for the suggestions.